# Error node-inspector

Tags: nodejs

He usado note-inspector por mas de 1 año y nunca he tenido problemas, pero ahora me salta este error y nunca llega a arrancar el debug.

Cual podría ser la causa y solución?

```
/deep/ combinator is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120 for more details.
Runtime.js:367 ReferenceError: bf is not defined
    at eval (InspectorBackendCommands.js:1)
    at evaluateScript (Runtime.js:153)
    at scriptSourceLoaded (Runtime.js:136)Runtime._reportError @ Runtime.js:367
Runtime.js:367 TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.WebInspector.NodeInspectorOverrides._overrideMainScriptType (NodeInspectorOverrides.js:31)
    at Object.WebInspector.NodeInspectorOverrides (NodeInspectorOverrides.js:9)
    at eval (NodeInspectorOverrides.js:214)
    at evaluateScript (Runtime.js:153)
    at scriptSourceLoaded (Runtime.js:136)Runtime._reportError @ Runtime.js:367
Runtime.js:367 TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at eval (BreakpointManager.js:942)
    at evaluateScript (Runtime.js:153)
    at scriptSourceLoaded (Runtime.js:136)Runtime._reportError @ Runtime.js:367
Runtime.js:367 TypeError: Cannot read property 'NetworkThroughputUnlimitedValue' of undefined
    at eval (OverridesUI.js:373)
    at evaluateScript (Runtime.js:153)
    at scriptSourceLoaded (Runtime.js:136)Runtime._reportError @ Runtime.js:367
Runtime.js:367 TypeError: Cannot read property 'addModelListener' of undefined
    at Object.WebInspector.CPUProfileType (CPUProfileView.js:394)
    at Object.WebInspector.ProfileTypeRegistry (ProfileTypeRegistry.js:12)
    at eval (ProfileTypeRegistry.js:43)
    at evaluateScript (Runtime.js:153)
    at scriptSourceLoaded (Runtime.js:136)Runtime._reportError @ Runtime.js:367
Runtime.js:367 TypeError: Cannot read property 'MessageLevel' of undefined
    at eval (SourceFrame.js:753)
    at evaluateScript (Runtime.js:153)
    at scriptSourceLoaded (Runtime.js:136)Runtime._reportError @ Runtime.js:367
Runtime.js:367 TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.WebInspector.ConsoleExtensions._extendConsoleDispatcher (ConsoleExtentions.js:17)
    at Object.WebInspector.ConsoleExtensions (ConsoleExtentions.js:11)
    at eval (ConsoleExtentions.js:36)
    at evaluateScript (Runtime.js:153)
    at scriptSourceLoaded (Runtime.js:136)Runtime._reportError @ Runtime.js:367
Runtime.js:367 TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at eval (ScriptFormatterEditorAction.js:135)
    at evaluateScript (Runtime.js:153)
    at scriptSourceLoaded (Runtime.js:136)Runtime._reportError @ Runtime.js:367
Runtime.js:367 TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
    at Object.WebInspector.InspectorView (InspectorView.js:99)
    at Object.WebInspector.Main._createAppUI (Main.js:194)
    at Object.WebInspector.Main._loaded (Main.js:118)
    at runOnWindowLoad (DOMExtension.js:805)
    at Object.WebInspector.Main (Main.js:40)
    at eval (Main.js:919)
    at evaluateScript (Runtime.js:153)
    at scriptSourceLoaded (Runtime.js:136)Runtime._reportError @ Runtime.js:367
Runtime.js:367 TypeError: WebInspector.Linkifier is not a constructor
    at Object.WebInspector.NetworkLogView (NetworkLogView.js:66)
    at Object.WebInspector.NetworkPanel (NetworkPanel.js:66)
    at Function.WebInspector.NetworkPanel._instance (NetworkPanel.js:408)
    at eval (NetworkPanel.js:13)
    at evaluateScript (Runtime.js:153)
    at scriptSourceLoaded (Runtime.js:136)Runtime._reportError @ Runtime.js:367
Runtime.js:367 TypeError: Cannot read property '_tabbedPane' of undefined
    at Object.WebInspector.SourcesOverrides._hideChromeSpecifics (SourcesOverrides.js:15)
    at Object.WebInspector.SourcesOverrides (SourcesOverrides.js:5)
    at eval (SourcesOverrides.js:63)
    at evaluateScript (Runtime.js:153)
    at scriptSourceLoaded (Runtime.js:136)Runtime._reportError @ Runtime.js:367
Runtime.js:367 TypeError: Cannot read property '_defaultKeyToActions' of undefined
    at eval (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node/main/MainOverrides.js:15:46)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.WebInspector.MainOverrides._unregisterShortcuts (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node/main/MainOverrides.js:13:33)
    at Object.WebInspector.MainOverrides (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node/main/MainOverrides.js:4:8)
    at eval (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node/main/MainOverrides.js:100:1)
    at evaluateScript (http://127.0.0.1:8080/Runtime.js:153:14)
    at scriptSourceLoaded (http://127.0.0.1:8080/Runtime.js:136:13)Runtime._reportError @ Runtime.js:367
```

Answer (score 0):

Por el mensaje de error **combinator is deprecated** pareciera que una dependencia que usa **node-inspector** ya está obsoleta, intenta verificar que versión tienes de **node-inspector** y actualizar a la última si ya salio alguna nueva.

Esta solo es una idea, por que nunca antes me ha dado ese error.

Comment: Tengo la version "node-inspector": "^0.12.8",
Aun asi he comenzado a utilizar "devtool"  para debuggear que no me da problemas... y sigue siendo bajo chrome.